# $Y=${$(x_j/j):(x_j)\in l_\infty$}. Is Y closed in $l_\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $Y=${$(x_j/j):(x_j)\in l_\infty$}. Is Y closed in $l_\infty$?

(I could not find any sequence in Y tending to some point outside Y. Please give some hint for such kind of sequence or any other hints/ways.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not closed.

Consider
$$
 y_j=\frac1{\sqrt{j}}, \quad (y_j)\in\ell^\infty.
$$

It is easy to see that $(y_j)\not\in Y$.

Now define $(x_j^n)$ via
$$
 x_j^n = y_j \cdot \mathbb 1_{j\leq n}
$$

Then $(x_j^n)\in Y$, and
$\| (x_j^n)- (y_j)\|_{\ell^\infty} \leq \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: What is $1_{j\leq} n$

Comment: $\mathbb 1_{j\leq n}$ is $1$ if $j\leq n$ but $0$ if $j>n$.